# Return List grouped by two properties using linq ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

So I have this Table with class `Report`:

[image: reportTable]

Based on the `ProductId` and `ReportType` I want to create a LINQ expression that returns a `List<ReportInnerResponse>`, where `ReportInnerResponse` contains the following:

```
    public class ReportInnerResponse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ReportType ReportType { get; set; }
        public int ReportCount { get; set; }
    }
```

So my final result would be something like this:

[image]

Here is my current code, but it does not work properly:

```
        public ActionResult GetReportsById(int id)
        {
            var reports = DbContext.Reports.GroupBy(x => new {x.ProductId, x.ReportType}).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).Where(x => x.ProductId == id).Select(r =>
            new Models.Response.ReportInnerResponse
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                ReportType = r.ReportType,
                ReportCount = DbContext.Reports.Where(x => x.ReportType == r.ReportType && x.ProductId == id).Count()
            }).ToList();
            return PartialView("_ProductReportDetails", reports);
        }
```

Main View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Finder.Models.Response.AdminReportResponse>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report Panel | Finder";
}

<h2>Report Panel</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            Seller
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th>
            Report Info
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="@item.Image" height="100px" width="100px" style="object-fit: contain" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @{ 
                    var price = item.Price.ToString("C");
                }
                @price
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.ReportCount >= 1)
                {
                    <span>@item.ReportCount</span>
                    @Html.Action("GetReportsById", new { id = item.Id })
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Partial View:

```
@model List<Finder.Models.Response.ReportInnerResponse>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-flag" style="margin-right:10px;"></i> See Reports
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Report Menu</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <p><span>@item.ReportCount</span>@item.ReportType</p>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide details on how/what exactly do you want as a result?

Comment: @FelipeOriani I want to return a `List<ReportInnerResponse>` that contains the count of a specific report with a specific ReportType and the name of that ReportType for each report

Comment: _"does not work properly"_ is not very informative? What is wrong? It throws an exception? wrong data is returned? No data is returned?

Comment: @GuruStron returns the same object for every item. I have a list of items, I click See reports, and they are all the same despite of the item.

Comment: @EL02 I would not say that your code looks fine (I think it is overcomplecated for the case) but it should produce the required result. I would check the UI code for the problem.

Comment: Can you please share `_ProductReportDetails`view?

Comment: Also what is `r.Id` in `new Models.Response.ReportInnerResponse { Id = r.Id,`? Does this even compile?

Comment: @GuruStron added them, and yes it does compile.

Comment: @EL02 `ReportInnerResponse.Id` - what Id should be here? Product one?

Comment: @GuruStron that Id doesnt matter, in fact I shouldnt have included it at all. It plays no role in this

Comment: @EL02 by the way. What version of EF Core are you using? Just guess - isn't it 2.x?

Comment: @GuruStron its just EF, not core. version 6.4.4

Comment: @EL02 are you using EF 6 inside ASP.NET Core? If yes - why? If not - why are you tagging the question with `asp.net-core` ?

Comment: @GuruStron EF on asp.net. I tagged asp net core because i thought it would be a quick linq fix where it wouldnt matter what version im using. I'll edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Id` property on `Models.Response.ReportInnerResponse` does not make much sense, TBH, since it represents grouping result (or it should be named `ProductId`). Remove it and try rewriting your query this way:

```cs
var reports = DbContext.Reports
    .Where(x => x.ProductId == id) // filter out not needed data before grouping
    .GroupBy(x => x.ReportType)
    .Select(g => new Models.Response.ReportInnerResponse
        {
            ReportType = g.Key,
            ReportCount = g.Count()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Nope, tried and produces the same result

Comment: @EL02 have you checked in the debugger if the `reports` variable contains wrong data?

Comment: Yes, and it returns the correct list for each item.

Comment: @EL02 sorry, I'm out of ideas. I don't have legacy MVC set up on my machine and it seems that issue is lying somewhere there (based on the query producing correct result). Check maybe there is some caching involved? Also try reloading the VS/Solution/Website (maybe even machine).

Comment: Found the issue. When I click the other button, it targets the first modal, since they all have the same id attribute. When checked in Inspect element it is correct. Now gotta find a way to add a different id to both the modal and the button target

Comment: Yay, fixed it. added a guid for id and target. Thanks a lot though